Do sinusoidal positional embeddings fundamentally limit context length?
In principle, it seems like we can generate endless sinusoidal positional embeddings. However, with respect to context window maximums, is there some limitation that sinusoidal positional embeddings have if we pretrain on a fixed window size but inference on a much larger set of sequence lengths? I imagine that, with large enough sequences, positional embeddings eventually duplicate due to the cyclical nature of the sin/cos functions, but I'm not 100% sure.
